# Graphic driver for ATI Radeon Xpress 200M on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have trouble finding the right driver for my graphic card on Ubuntu 9.10. My graphic card is ATI Radeon Xpress 200M. With Ubuntu default driver, I have had problems  when doing some OpenGL graphics programming or when watching youtube, the graphics goes slower than the sounds.

Could anybody help? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old ATI cards do not work well with Linux. ATI closed the drivers and wouldn't let the open source community have access to them for a period of time. You can go to the ATI site and download the drivers they have. If they are  not there, or you can't get them to work, there have been a few people set up their xorg.conf files just right to get them working, but I have never seen it, or been able to do it with my Radion 2600xt. Your best bet to get good performance in Linux is going to be grabbing a cheap nVida card. They are supported much better than ATI.